# run script for all users

Tags: bash, scripting, users

I put some script on my ubuntu linux in /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh but it's just work on my user.

But it's work only user logged in not when I use sudo.

```
# myscript.sh
export MYVAL="HELLO"

echo $MYVAL // HELLO

sudo echo $MYVAL // ?!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please explain better what are you trying to achieve?
.profile is executed with a user privileges, when the user logs on.
So in order to use sudo in .profile you have to put user/group, user belongs to in /etc/sudoers

ok, sudo strips environment variables for various security reasons.
In order to do what you want, you have to put in /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults        env_reset  
Defaults        env_keep += "MYVARIABLE YETANOTHER"
```

Comment: i need to define a variable that can i use in each user with and without sudo. it's so simple.